# Geolocation Phonegap Android not working

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, maps

I have tried everything to get geolocation working on my emulator (target 2.2), I have used telnet and issued a 'geo fix ' followed by the longitude and latitude. I have edited my Android manifest to give me permission but I am not sure why it will not show me the google map which is centered around my location. If I put any coordinates into the setcentered function for the map but when I put in my coordinates it doesn't show up.
This is the code I have been examining for hours:

```
<!DOCTYPE html "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Google Maps JavaScript API Example</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=AIzaSyBrnId8UIeAeDTMr2sVi-g86izgdb2KhVo&sensor=true"
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
// Wait for PhoneGap to load
// PhoneGap is ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, [maximumAge: 3000, timeout:          5000, enableHighAccuracy: 
<!--position.coords.latitude-->
initialize() 
(GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
map.setCenter(new GLatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude), 13)
map.setUIToDefault();
// Add 10 markers to the map at random locations
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
}
}      
</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance, I have been trying to solve this for so many hours, what I need is for google maps to appear and the centre of google maps is my location.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of my quick observations.  You don't appear to have defined an onDeviceReady function that will get called when PhoneGap has initialized.  Below is a copy of the PhoneGap sample code showing how to use onDeviceReady from [the PhoneGap documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html).

Do you see how this code has defined a function called `onDeviceReady` where the comments say that PhoneGap methods are safe to call.

You also don't appear to load the PhoneGap JavaScript `<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Call onDeviceReady when PhoneGap is loaded.
    //
    // At this point, the document has loaded but phonegap-1.0.0.js has not.
    // When PhoneGap is loaded and talking with the native device,
    // it will call the event `deviceready`.
    // 
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, looking more at your code, you are not using `GBrowserIsCompatible()` correctly.  You need to use this function call inside an `if` statement.

I would change your code as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    // PhoneGap is ready
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    <!--position.coords.latitude-->
    function onDeviceReady() {
       if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, [maximumAge: 3000, timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: // some code is missing here!
           map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
           map.setCenter(new GLatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude), 13)
           map.setUIToDefault();
           // Add 10 markers to the map at random locations
           var bounds = map.getBounds();
           var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
           var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
           var lngSpan = northEast.lng() - southWest.lng();
           var latSpan = northEast.lat() - southWest.lat();
       } else {
           // add code here to display error that device is not compatible
       }
    }      
</script>
</head>
    <body onunload="GUnload()">
```

Comment: Also, the script HTML tag to load the PhoneGap JavaScript needs to use the correct name of the JavaScript file.  This name depends on the version of PhoneGap that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*enter code here*/ function handle_errors(error)
    {
        switch(error.code)
        {
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED: alert("user did not share geolocation data");
            break;

            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: alert("could not detect current position");
            break;

            case error.TIMEOUT: alert("retrieving position timedout");
            break;

            default: alert("unknown error");
            break;
        }
    }

    function handle_geolocation_query(position) {  
        var text = "Latitude: "  + position.coords.latitude  + "<br/>" +  
        "Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude + "<br/>" +  
        "Accuracy: "  + position.coords.accuracy  + "m<br/>" +  
        "Time: " + new Date(position.timestamp);  
        //$("#info").html(text); 

        // alert(text);

        var image_url ='';
        image_url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?path=color:0x0000ff|weight:5|40.737102,-73.990318|40.749825,-73.987963&zoom=14&size=260x300&sensor=true";


        $("#info").slideUp('slow');
        $("#map").slideDown('slow');

        $('#map').html('<img src="'+image_url+'" />');

    } 

/*enter code here*/<a class="request_appoint_ment" href="javascript:void(0);" data-transition="none" id="btnInit">Mark Vehicle Location</a>


/*enter code here*/<div id="info" style="display:none;"><img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" style="padding:50px 0 50px 100px;" /></div>
                    <div id="map" style="display:none; padding-bottom:20px;"></div>


/*enter code here*/$( '#btnInit' ).live( 'click',function(event){
                         $("#map").slideUp('slow');
                         $("#info").slideDown('slow');
                         $('#markmaptype').val(1);
                         initiate_watchlocation();
                         });
```

use this code, it is working for me

Comment: your missing a large chunk of it